# How to find the wireless MAC address (aka BSSID) of any wireless access point

Tags: networking, ubuntu, mac-address, aircrack-ng

I have aircrack-ng 1.2 beta 3 and I wanted to know how I can find the wireless MAC address (aka BSSID) of any wireless access point with aircrack-ng (or any other program).

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: MAC address of a *network*?

Comment: I'm 90% sure (s)he means an access point/router's WAN MAC Address a.k.a. "wireless MAC address (also called as BSSID)" as described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_access_point . "Why no one no help?"

Comment: This answer looks to be the right direction to go http://askubuntu.com/a/351517/129271

Comment: And doesn't the default network manager show the BSSID's of available (visible) AP's, no aircrack required?

Comment: With Ubuntu, you can also use `nmcli -f BSSID dev wifi list`. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1094526/8822) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/389529/8822) answer on askubuntu.

Answer (score 6):

Use **`iw device scan`** to show all information about currently visible networks. The output has more than an entire screenful per network, so use `grep` to trim it down:

```
$ sudo iw wlan0 scan | egrep "^BSS|SSID:"
BSS 24:a4:3c:9e:d2:84(on wlan0) -- associated
    SSID: eduroam
BSS 24:a4:3c:ae:df:83(on wlan0)
    SSID: Example multi-AP network
BSS dc:9f:db:30:c1:7a(on wlan0)
    SSID: Example multi-AP network
BSS 00:19:3b:99:e2:80(on wlan0)
    SSID: TEO Wi-Fi
```

For some very old Wi-Fi card drivers, you'll need the `iwlist device scan` tool instead:

```
$ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | egrep "Address:|ESSID:"
          Cell 01 - Address: 24:A4:3C:9E:D2:84
                    ESSID:"eduroam"
          Cell 02 - Address: 24:A4:3C:AE:DF:83
                    ESSID:"Example multi-AP network"
          Cell 03 - Address: DC:9F:DB:30:C1:7A
                    ESSID:"Example multi-AP network"
          Cell 04 - Address: 24:A4:3C:9E:D2:16
                    ESSID:"Example multi-AP network"
```

Aircrack also comes with the **`airodump-ng`** tool which repeatedly shows all networks it sees. (You need to enable monitor mode first, using airmon-ng.)

Comment: Isn't a BSSID the IP Address?

Comment: No, it isn't. Wi-Fi access points are similar to Ethernet switches – they only care about Ethernet packets and a specific device is identified by its MAC address and "Basic Service Set ID" is just a fancy name for that. (While most APs _do_ have IP addresses for purpose of adjusting configuration, usually you cannot find that out in any way.)